# Field type not being honor in Kibana/Elasticsearch

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm using a logstash plug-in for a Java app using logback to forward logs on to my logstash server.  I've setup a filter definition as follows:

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 2856
    codec => json_lines
  }
}

filter {
  mutate {
    convert => {
      "tenantId" => "integer"
      "userId" => "integer"
    }
  }
}
```

Logs are being forwarded on to Elasticsearch using the following config:

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
    user => "user"
    password => "secure"
  }
}
```

The index is just going to logstash-, and when I inspect the mappings in Elasticsearch, I see the following:

```
  "logstash-2016.04.25" : {
      "mappings" : {
         "logs" : {
            "_all" : {
               "omit_norms" : true,
               "enabled" : true
            },
            "properties" : {
               ...
               "userId" : {
                  "type" : "long"
               },
               "tenantId" : {
                  "type" : "long"
               },
               ...
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

So I can see that the fields are being set with an appropriate type, but they are neither analyzed nor defined as long values when I check Kibana.  What am I missing?

Comment: Have you updated your mappings in Kibana? Do you have other indices which have the same fields, but different types?

Comment: I haven't touched Kibana at all actually, and no other indicies are created.  I actually set this up on a clean server before any log data started flowing.  What updates would I need to make on Kibana?

Comment: If these are new fields in an index, then you need to tell Kibana to refresh its field list (Settings -> Indices) so that it can use them when visualizing. Do you even see them when in Discover mode?

Comment: That was it.  I just needed to refresh the Kibana index and all was well.  If you post this as the answer, I'll accept it to give you the appropriate recognition.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these are new fields in a given index, you'll need to tell Kibana to [refresh](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/settings.html#reload-fields) it's field listing.

> #### Reloading the Index Fields List
>
> When you add an index mapping, Kibana automatically scans the indices that match the pattern to display a list of the index fields. You can reload the index fields list to pick up any newly-added fields.
>
> Reloading the index fields list also resets Kibana’s popularity counters for the fields. The popularity counters keep track of the fields you’ve used most often within Kibana and are used to sort fields within lists.
>
> To reload the index fields list:
>
> 1. Go to the **Settings > Indices** tab.
> 2. Select an index pattern from the Index Patterns list.
> 3. Click the pattern’s **Reload** button.